# To show the inequality $\|A\|\geq\max\{\|u_1\|,\ldots,\|u_q\|,\|\vec{v_1}\|,\ldots,\|\vec{v_q}\|\}$

Tags: matrices, inequality, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, vector-analysis

Let $A\in$ $\mathbb{C}^{p\times q}$ with column $u_1,\ldots,u_q$ and rows $\vec{v_1},\ldots,\vec{v_p}$. show that 
$$\|A\|\geq\max\{\|u_1\|,\ldots,\|u_q\|,\|\vec{v_1}\|,\ldots,\|\vec{v_q}\|\}$$ and that the inequality may be strict.

Comment: What is $|| A ||$ here ? (there are several matrix norms)

Comment: unit norm matrix

Comment: You mean ${\sf sup}\frac{||Av||}{||v||}$ ?

Comment: whats definition of this norm ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: Yes

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the [operator norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm#Equivalent_definitions), here is a hint:
$\|A\|=\max_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|=\max_{\|y\|=1}\|y^\ast A\|$. Now take $x$ and $y$ as vectors from the canonical bases of $\mathbb{C}^q$ and $\mathbb{C}^p$.